# Spring Boot Task Executor queue issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot (1.4.1) application which uses following Task Executor Configuration:

```
 @Bean ("taskExecutor")
 TaskExecutor taskExecutor (Environment env) {
         ThreadPoolTaskExecutor t = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
         t.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt( env.getProperty("ed.corePoolSize"))); //2
         t.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt( env.getProperty("ed.maxPoolSize")));   //10
         t.setQueueCapacity(Integer.parseInt( env.getProperty("ed.queueCapacity"))); //50
         t.setThreadNamePrefix(env.getProperty("ed.threadNamePrefix"));
         t.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
         t.setKeepAliveSeconds(Integer.parseInt( env.getProperty("ed.keepAliveSeconds"))); //120
         return t;
     }
```

The implementation of this-

```
TaskExecutor taskExecutor = (TaskExecutor) beanFactory.getBean("taskExecutor");
        taskExecutor.execute(taskNameUpdate);
```

where taskNameUpdate is a Runnable task.

When the user sent 17 requests it processed 2 requests in two threads (Say T1 and T2). When T1 finishes execution of the first task it picks task17 from the queue where it should pick task3. The Bigger problem is when T2 finishes the current task it also start processing task 17. Both of threads fishes task 17 and starts processing task 17 again.

As a temporary fix, I have set corePoolSize=10 and requested not to send more than 10 batches at the same time.

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor just configures a ThreadPoolExecutor which uses a blocking queue. What you are describing is totally out of whack.

Comment: Meaning the blocking queue does not work, or the user is sending requests out of order and repeatedly

Comment: Hi @efekctive thanks for the explanation. I have figured out the problem. I haven't shared the runnable task creation code.

Comment: The problem was not with the taskExecutor.The problem was while creating runnable task the request object was converted with Google Gson library and I haven't defined request object as Component with Scope of the prototype. As a result, the object reference was same for all the queued object (as they are in the main thread). So the queue was returning the same object again and again. If the number of requests is less than the corePoolSize it executes in a new thread so no issue was found.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for sharing the solution